# Bz2 every file in a dir

Tags: linux, unix, compression, centos, bzip2

I am running centos and I have around 1,300 files in a folder that each need to be bzipped individually. What would be the easiest way of handing this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If all the files are in a single directory then:

```
bzip2 *
```

Is enough. A more robust approach is:

```
find . -type f -exec bzip2 {} +
```

Which will compress every file in the current directory and its sub-directories, and will work even if you have tens of thousands of files (using * will break if there are too many files in the directory).

If your computer has multiple cores, then you can improve this further by compressing multiple files at once. For example, if you would like to compress 4 files concurrently, use:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P4 bzip2
```

In case you get a permission denied error, put another sudo before xargs:

```
find . -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -0 -n1 -P4 bzip2
```

Comment: I don't understand where in your last command you specify to use bzip2

Comment: What is the meaning of `{} +`?

Comment: There is a very good answer to Lee's question/comment here: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec)

Comment: For anyone curious on applying this to decompression, it's enough to simply pass in that option: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P4 bzip2 -d`

Answer (score 3):

To bzip2 on a multi-core Mac, you can issue the following command (when you're inside the folder you want to bzip)

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P14 /opt/local/bin/bzip2
```

This will bzip every file recursively inside the folder your terminal is in using 14 CPU cores simultaneously.

You can adjust how many cores to use by editing

```
 -P14
```

If you don't know where the bzip2 binary is, you can issue the following command to figure it out

```
which bzip2
```

The output of that command is what you can replace

```
/opt/local/bin/bzip2
```

with

Answer (score 1):

I have written below script to `bzip2` files to another directory

```
#!/bin/bash
filedir=/home/vikrant_singh_rana/test/*

for filename in $filedir; do
name=$(basename "$filename" | sed -e 's/\.[^.]*$//')
bzip2 -dc $filename > /home/vikrant_singh_rana/unzipfiles/$name
done
```

my sample file name was like

```
2001_xyz_30Sep2020_1400-30Sep2020_1500.csv.bz2
```

I was not able to get any direct command, hence made this. This is working fine as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From inside the directory: `bzip2 *`

Answer (score 0):

```
find PATH_TO_FOLDER -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bzip2 -zk {} \;
```